# How to modify ASP NET Web API Route matching to allow parameters with slashes inside?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-routing

We're using RavenDB on the backend and so all the DB keys are strings that contain forward slashes e.g. `users/1`.

AFAIK there's no way to use the default ASP NET Web API route matching engine to match a parameter like this, without using a catch-all which means the key must be the last thing on the URL. I tried adding a regex constraint of `users/d+` but it didn't seem to make a difference, the route wasn't matched.

What bits would I have to replace to do just enough custom route matching to allow this, preferably without crippling the rest of the route matching. For example, using `url: "{*route}"` and a custom constraint that did full regex matching would work but may work unexpectedly with other route configurations.

If your answer comes with some sample code, so much the better.

Comment: Take a look here  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17218454/how-do-i-setup-a-route-to-capture-all-subsequent-url-segments-after-the-controll/17218690#17218690

Comment: Please read question again: `without using a catch-all which means the key must be the last thing on the URL`

Comment: Sorry - missed that. As far as i'm aware, this can't be done using the default routing engine then. You'll either have to use a catch-all or look at writing a custom route constraint (but that's still going to use a catch-all, but will give you more flexibility)

Comment: The proper way would be to override IHttpRoute and do the processing in GetRouteData but it seems to never get called!! See https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/discussions/451219 - perhaps you have any insights to share.

Comment: Found a way! See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that it is possible to do this by defining a custom route. In MVC4 (last stable released 4.0.30506.0), it is not possible to do by implementing `IHttpRoute` as per specification but by defining a custom MVC-level `Route` and adding it directly to the `RouteTable`. For details see [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12544150/asp-net-web-api-rtm-and-subdomain-routes), [2](https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/discussions/451219). The `RegexRoute` implementation below is based on the implementation [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20080401025712/http://www.iridescence.no/Posts/Defining-Routes-using-Regular-Expressions-in-ASPNET-MVC.aspx) with mods from the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12544150/asp-net-web-api-rtm-and-subdomain-routes).

Define `RegexRoute`:

```
public class RegexRoute : Route
{
    private readonly Regex urlRegex;

    public RegexRoute(string urlPattern, string routeTemplate, object defaults, object constraints = null)
        : base(routeTemplate, new RouteValueDictionary(defaults), new RouteValueDictionary(constraints), new RouteValueDictionary(), HttpControllerRouteHandler.Instance)
    {
        urlRegex = new Regex(urlPattern, RegexOptions.Compiled);
    }

    public override RouteData GetRouteData(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        string requestUrl = httpContext.Request.AppRelativeCurrentExecutionFilePath.Substring(2) + httpContext.Request.PathInfo;

        Match match = urlRegex.Match(requestUrl);

        RouteData data = null;

        if (match.Success)
        {
            data = new RouteData(this, RouteHandler);

            // add defaults first
            if (null != Defaults)
            {
                foreach (var def in Defaults)
                {
                    data.Values[def.Key] = def.Value;
                }
            }

            // iterate matching groups
            for (int i = 1; i < match.Groups.Count; i++)
            {
                Group group = match.Groups[i];

                if (group.Success)
                {
                    string key = urlRegex.GroupNameFromNumber(i);

                    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(key) && !Char.IsNumber(key, 0)) // only consider named groups
                    {
                        data.Values[key] = group.Value;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return data;
    }
}
```

Add this `DelegatingHandler` to avoid a `NullReference` due to some other bug:

```
public class RouteByPassingHandler : DelegatingHandler
    {
        protected override System.Threading.Tasks.Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            HttpMessageInvoker invoker = new HttpMessageInvoker(new HttpControllerDispatcher(request.GetConfiguration()));
            return invoker.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
        }
    }
```

Add handler and route directly to the `RouteTable`:

```
RouteTable.Routes.Add(new RegexRoute(@"^api/home/index/(?<id>\d+)$", "test", new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }));

        config.MessageHandlers.Add(new RouteByPassingHandler());
```

Et voila!

**EDIT**: This solution has problems when the API is self-hosted (instead of using a WebHost) and requires further work to make it work with both. If this is interesting to anyone, please leave a comment and I'll post my solution.