# ASP NET Web API 2/MVC 5 Attribute routing and constraints with forward slashes

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-web-api-routing

We're using RavenDB on the backend and so all the DB keys are strings that contain forward slashes e.g. `users/1` in `/api/users/1/foo`.

This question superseeds [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17856926/how-to-modify-asp-net-web-api-route-matching-to-allow-parameters-with-slashes-in) question for the previous version of the Web API.
The solution I came up with v1 works fine but it's a little messy setting up the tables. v2 introduces attribute routing which would be a very welcome change.

However, I could find no way to match parts of the URL that contain forward slashes. I tried creating a custom constraint but it seems that the pipeline will split the URL segments before trying to match it.

What's the simplest way to extend the URL => attribute matcher such that it can accept constraints that contain full-blown regexes (i.e. not regexes limited to one segment)?

Comment: Have you seen [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/10/17/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5.aspx#custom-route-constraints), in particular the section on Custom Route Constraints?

Comment: As mentioned above, this allows you to specify constraints that span only one segment or in other words that do not contain a `/`. `/foo/bar/baz` becomes `["foo", "bar", "baz"]` before applying the constraints so it's not possible to make a constraint for e.g. `bar/baz`.

Comment: I'm looking for an answer to this, as well... have you discovered a solution?

Comment: No, unfortunately I left that project so never looked further into it. I also asked at the MVC forums and never got an answer. I would venture to guess the only way is to write your own routing implementation...